# OUTER JOIN with SQL across multiple tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, outer-join

I have a SQL Server 2008 database. This database has three tables:

**Person**

```
  - Id
  - FullName
  - MembershipStatusId (nullable)
  - HairStyleId (nullable)
```

**MembershipStatus**

```
  - Id
  - Name
```

**HairStyle**

```
  - Id
  - ColorName
  - Description
```

I need to create a query that lists all of the people in my database. Because `MembershipStatusId` and `HairStyleId` are both nullable, I know I need to do a left outer join. However, because there are multiple tables, I'm not sure how to do it. With a single left outer join, I know I can do this:

```
SELECT
  p.*,
  m.Name as 'MembershipStatus',
  -- how do i include the person's hair color as part of my result set?
FROM
  Person p LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MembershipStatus m ON p.[MembershipStatusId]
```

However, I'm not sure how to add the left outer join for the hair style name.  Can somebody please tell me how to include the Person's hair color?

Thank you!

Comment: Both of your joins are on primary keys, so as per the answers so far, its fairly straightforward. (Outer joins start to get tricky one you have two or more X-to-many outer joins to deal with.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just do another `LEFT JOIN` to include the HairStyle Table

```
SELECT
  p.*,
  m.Name as 'MembershipStatus',
  h.ColorName
FROM Person p 
LEFT JOIN MembershipStatus m 
    ON p.[MembershipStatusId] = m. Id
LEFT JOIN HairStyle h
    ON p.HairStyleId = h.id
```

See a demo on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a285/1)

Comment: What happens if MembershipId is null, but HairStyleId is not? Will it still work? In my mind, the query would quit if MembershipStatusId was null. But, I might be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Since it is an outer join you should still get the result even if it is null, I updated my answer with a sql fiddle demo

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    Person.id,
    MembershipStatus.Name AS MemberShip,
    HairStyle.ColorName AS HairStyleColorName
FROM
    Person
    LEFT JOIN MembershipStatus
        ON Person.MembershipStatusId=MembershipStatus.Id
    LEFT JOIN HairStyle
        ON Person.HairStyleId = HairStyle.Id
```